# Unable to add uiview with label in viewForHeaderInSection()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm a beginner trying to learn Swift

I'm trying to make my own section header by creating a uiview and adding a label to it before returning it. However the label is never displayed, only the uiview.

I cannot see what I'm doing wrong?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionHeaderView = UIView()
    sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    sectionHeaderView.layer.cornerRadius = 0

    let sectionLabel = UILabel()
    sectionLabel.text = "Test"
    sectionLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    sectionLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

    sectionHeaderView.addSubview(sectionLabel)

    return sectionHeaderView
}
```

Comment: You never size the label to fit the text. And there's no need for the view. Just create and return the label as the header view.

Comment: ah, so the label is like 0x0 pixels in my code? I'm creating a uiview because I want to do some designy stuff in my section header later on, so I figured I need it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add `sectionLabel.sizeToFit()`
Thanks maddy!